# Keep the dropdown down after selected in Element (Vue) Autocomplete

Tags: vue.js, autocomplete, element

I am using Element for my project.
When I use Autocomplete Input, I want to keep the dropdown intact when selecting an element, and only hide it when blurring. Can anyone help me?
https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reasonable way to do that without forking the library or writing your own component.

Here is the code in elements source that always closes the autocomplete when a choice is selected:

```js
select(item) {
  this.$emit('input', item[this.valueKey]);
  this.$emit('select', item);
  this.$nextTick(_ => {
    this.suggestions = []; // This will always close the suggestions tooltip
    this.highlightedIndex = -1;
  });
}
```

[Source](https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/blob/dev/packages/autocomplete/src/autocomplete.vue#L236).

If you don't want to fork the whole library and you are importing the components individually, you may be able to 1. import the `el-autocomplete` component, 2. overwrite the `select` method, 3. register the modified component.

Comment: thank you. when i try to import the autocomplete form node_modules like this 
import ElAutocomplete from '../../../node_modules/element-ui/packages/autocomplete/src/autocomplete'
there is an error message: "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file"

Comment: @xXSteroidsXx Yes, depending on your builder, you will have to include a loader for .vue files if you don't have one already. Intro here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html#For-Users-New-to-Module-Build-Systems-in-JavaScript